# What atomicity guarantees - if any - does Kafka have regarding batch writes?

Tags: apache-kafka, atomic

We're now moving one of our services from pushing data through legacy communication tech to Apache Kafka. 
The current logic is to send a message to IBM MQ and retry if errors occur. I want to repeat that, but I don't have any idea about what guarantees the broker provide in that scenario. 
Let's say I send 100 messages in a batch via producer via Java client library. Assuming it reaches the cluster, is there a possibility only part of it be accepted (e.g. a disk is full, or some partitions I touch in my write are under-replicated)? Can I detect that problem from my producer and retry only those messages that weren't accepted? 
I searched for `kafka atomicity guarantee` but came up empty, may be there's a well-known term for it

Answer (score 1):

When you say you send 100 messages in one batch, you mean, you want to control this number of messages or be ok letting the producer batch a certain amount of messages and then send the batch ?

Because not sure you can control the number of produced messages in one producer batch, the API will queue them and batch them for you, but without guarantee of batch them all together ( I'll check that though).

If you're ok with letting the API batch a certain amount of messages for you, here is some clues about how they are acknowledged.

When dealing with producer, Kafka comes with some kind of reliability regarding writes ( also "batch writes")

As stated in this slideshare post :
https://www.slideshare.net/miguno/apache-kafka-08-basic-training-verisign (83)

```
The original list of messages is partitioned (randomly if the default partitioner is used) based on their destination partitions/topics, i.e. split into smaller batches. 
Each post-split batch is sent to the respective leader broker/ISR (the individual send()’s happen sequentially), and each is acked by its respective leader broker according to request.required.acks
```

So regarding atomicity.. Not sure the whole batch will be seen as atomic regarding the above behavior. Maybe you can assure to send your batch of message using the same key for each message as they will go to the same partition, and thus maybe become atomic

If you need more clarity about acknowlegment rules when producing, here how it works As stated here https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/producer.html :

```
You can control the durability of messages written to Kafka through the acks setting. 
The default value of "1" requires an explicit acknowledgement from the partition leader that the write succeeded. 
The strongest guarantee that Kafka provides is with "acks=all", which guarantees that not only did the partition leader accept the write, but it was successfully replicated to all of the in-sync replicas.
```

You can also look around producer enable.idempotence behavior if you aim having no duplicates while producing.

Yannick

Comment: I'm ok with client doing batching for me (I'm aware of the internal queue) - sorry I wasn't clear in the question. I can't specify the same key for all of the messages in a batch because I need partitioning based on other field

Comment: so if the client send queue fills up, and it sends 3 micro-batches to each of the respective partition leafers, of which one is acked - I guess it's up to client to decide whether to throw exception or not?

Comment: Yeah, client side you can do a get() on the future result of your KafkaProducer.send() call ( asynchronous), and in the Metadatas, If I'm correct you should have something like result per partition . (```Map[TopicPartition, LogAppendResult]``` according to ReplicaManager class code). 
In this future you will have metadata and exception ( if error occured), you can check this exception and do whatever you might think useful.

Comment: there's another option - to use [idempotent producer](https://www.cloudkarafka.com/blog/2019-04-10-apache-kafka-idempotent-producer-avoiding-message-duplication.html). it has some limitations, main one is `acks=all` setting is a must, meaning producer will stall if at least one of your brokers is down